# How do i enable lines that snap and align my objects in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Hey how do i enable lines that snap and align my objects in photoshop? I had this before but now its gone, it really helped me with aligning as the object would snap to the right place when i moved it.

Answer (score 1):

Check your settings to see if the following are checked: View -> Snap To and View -> Snap.